# Database for different types of products

Tags: mysql, database

How the database structure would be for different types of products.
  For a shopping cart which only sells clothes will have fields in products tables,

```
 id
 name
 color
 size - enum(s,m,l,xl)
```

For a shop sells other products like shoes which may have sizes in differntly like,

```
id 
name
color
size - 6,7,8,9 etc
```

For a shop sells other products like mobile phones,

```
id 
name
color
model
```

As one can see the fields change depending on the products.  Can someone tell me how to have all the fields in a single shopping cart products table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding the attributes in the column names, a general attribute table is used:

```
product_id
attr_name - color, size, model, etc.
attr_value
```

You join this with the products table to get all the attributes of a particular item.